# Can pynput handle input from a specific keyboard only? If yes, how can this be achieved?

Tags: python-3.x, hardware, pynput

If several physical keyboards are connected to a system, or a single physical keyboard is connected but a touch screen is also used in the same time, can pynput be configured to filter the input by device, or I should go one level down and use something else?

I went through the documentation but nothing gave me any clue so far.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I didn't find a solution. I am afraid pynput might not work as low-level as needed. But not sure yet.

Comment: Probably you are correct. I can't find anything either.